# Remove Online Accounts in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, gnome3, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to remove the "Online Accounts" found on Settings on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

I have found these gsettings and am suspicious they may have something to do with that section of Settings...

`org.gnome.ControlCenter last-panel 'online-accounts'
org.gnome.online-accounts whitelisted-providers ['all']`

When I try to find the possibles values for the keys, nothing is returned...

`$ gsettings range org.gnome.online-accounts whitelisted-providers 
type as
$ gsettings range org.gnome.ControlCenter last-panel
type s`

If these are the pertinent settings, what do they need to be changed to? And how do you go about finding the possible values?

If these are not the settings, where should I look next?

Answer (score 1):

To hide the *Online Accounts* panel in *Gnome Settings*:

1. Close *Gnome Settings*
2. Choose between these options:

   - copy the `/usr/share/applications/gnome-online-accounts-panel.desktop` file to the `~/.local/share/applications/` directory (create it first if not exists yet) and append the line `Hidden=true` to the file
   - move/remove the `/usr/share/applications/gnome-online-accounts-panel.desktop` file (but this may be created again after a system update)

(tested in Gnome 3.32)

You can also remove all online account types from the whitelist with:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.online-accounts whitelisted-providers "[]"
```